# If my motherboard only supports minimum DDR3 1066MHz ram and I have 639.9 MHz ram, will it work?

Tags: memory, motherboard, compatibility

I'm going to upgrade my PC to a newer [MB](http://www.msi.com/product/motherboard/Z97-GAMING-5.html#hero-specification), but not my [RAM](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct102464ba160b). One allows the following frequencies: `DDR3 1066/1333/1600/1866*/2000*/2133*/2200*/2400*/2600*/2666*/2800*/3000*/3100*/3200*/3300*(*OC) MHz`, while the other is currently running at 639.9 MHz.

Will they be compatible?

Comment: if the motherboard has a minimum requirement, probably not

Comment: DDR3 does not even support that frequency.

Comment: @Ramhound Why does the website say 400MHz, then? http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct102464ba160b Could it be wrong?

Comment: Make up your mind.  Your question indicated, 639.9 MHz, now your something else entirely.

Comment: Well that's what Speccy says I'm running. http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3449#sp Is my current MB at the moment.

Comment: **The new motherboard specifically highlights that [DDR3-1600](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/ct102464ba160b) memory is supported**  The only question should be, is does the new motherboard support UDIMMs, and my educated guess would be it does indeed.  The module is simply, Unbuffered and NON-ECC, which most consumer boards use anyways

Comment: [I have no idea where they are getting 400 MHz from](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM) DDR3-1600 does not run at 400 MHz.  I can't figure out how you get 639.9 Mhz

Comment: @Ramhound - Not sure if this means anything to you - http://valid.x86.fr/0qnfah - DDR-SDRAM frequency 639.9 MHZ Ratio 3:8, timings 8-8-8-23-31-1 (tCAS-tRC-tRP-tRAS-tCS-tCR)

Comment: That is the CPU's memory frequency.  I am talking about the frequency of the memory.  But the disparity is explained all the same

Answer (score 0):

According to your links:

Your RAM Specs:  DDR3 PC3-12800 • CL=11 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • **DDR3-1600** • 1.5V • 1024Meg x 64

New Motherboard Specs: **DDR3** 1066/1333/**1600**/1866*/2000*/2133*/2200*/2400*/2600*/2666*/2800*/3000*/3100*/3200*/3300*(*OC) HMz

According to those specs, they are compatible.

Also, on the Crucial RAM page you linked, they have a "Will this work with my system?" compatibility checker, and that MSI motherboard is listed.  [According to that](http://www.crucial.com/usa/en/z97-gaming-5/CT5862069):

> This part is compatible!